# Reading icon in a .exe with tkinter's iconbitmap

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, py2exe, pyinstaller

My app is built into a single .exe file with `py2exe`. Instead of this code (which works when I have a .ico file) :

```
root.iconbitmap(default='test.ico')
```

I would like to use

```
root.iconbitmap(default='test.exe')
```

because since I have a single `.exe` file, I don't have a `.ico` file anymore...

It doesn't work :

```
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "D:\temp\test.exe" not defined
```

This file exists, but it seems that `iconbitmap` cannot read an icon from a .exe with embedded icons...

**How to read icons embedded in a .exe file with tkinter's `iconbitmap` ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can try to generate the icon *on the fly* just before the main loop of your application as in the third answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550050/removing-the-tk-icon-on-python-tkinter-windows). (Still you need to figure out how to write your icon to the string, but maybe that's a good question too!)

Comment: Yes I don't know either how to do this.
A more direct option would be to extract and use the icon from the .exe, but how ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the icon has to be a `.ico` file, you could try to convert your image into a `.ico` file, for example here is some code I had to use for a Tkinter program and you can use the second line to convert your image into a .ico file to then use it:

```
ico = Image.open('Image_dossier/Cover.png')
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ico)
root.wm_iconphoto(False, photo)
```