# Changing the default tkinter logo (python 2.7, windows)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have tried the following code to change the default Tk logo in the upper left corner:

```
import Tkinter as Tkinter

class window(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.iconbitmap(default='Logo.ico') 
        self.initialize()


    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = window(None)
    app.title('Window')
    app.mainloop()
```

The problem is that it does nothing.. no error message and no logo change. Logo.ico is a file in the same directory as the script.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550050/removing-the-tk-icon-on-python-tkinter-windows answer should help.

Comment: @W1ll1amvl Yes I saw that thanks. This works fine for me but not when I put it in a class as above. I must be doing something syntactically wrong but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Ok, so I tried this on python 3, windows, (obviously changing Tkinter to tkinter) and everything worked fine. Maybe the computer you are on has something to do with it.

Comment: i just tried this in python 2.7.6 without any modification and used the python logo (renamed) this worked fine, are you sure there is nothing wrong with your icon file?

Comment: @W1ll1amvl Ah yes that seems to be the case. I have no idea why but this works on my laptop but not on my PC. Both run windows 7 with the same version of python. Weird. Thanks.

Comment: I could **not** reproduce the problem on a PC with: `OS: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1 (32-bit), Python: 2.7.3`. It works as expected. Try supplying another icon file, maybe the one you use has some problem?

Comment: @Fenikso Thanks fr trying. It turns out that it must be an install issue on my PC because it worked well on my laptop. I'll add an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that what I posted is the correct syntax. There seems to be an issue with the python install on my desktop PC because the code works perfectly on my laptop. I guess it's time for a reinstallation.