# How to remove the logo from a Tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I create a python window (Tkinter) and I want to remove an icon from it and add new icon to python window.

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550050/removing-the-tk-icon-on-python-tkinter-windows)

Comment: K thanks Paul... I got the answer...