# Python : How to remove the tkinter icon

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Eyery single tkinter import creates a tkinter window with a winged sign

on the top. Here's a screenshot:[image: tkinter_screenshot]

Any ideas how to remove it? Thanks in advance!

I need the answer for Windows, not for UNIX

Comment: It is a duplicate, right, but it only works on UNIX

Comment: The first answer in the link gives windows and UNIX solutions.

Comment: It may be but I tried all answers out. NO ONE worked :-0

Comment: Please add an example of what you have tried.

Comment: Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
============ RESTART: C:\Users\timur\Documents\Phyton\New_book.py ============
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\timur\Documents\Phyton\New_book.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import ImageTk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
>>>

Comment: Do you want to have more???

Comment: That appears to be an import error with the Pillow module, I'm not seeing the relation to Tkinter.

Comment: Of course. You are right. Can you tell me sth. about this "Pillow module"?

Comment: It is used for image processing, it appears to not be installed, opening command prompt and typing: py -m pip install Pillow , should install it, if you are planning on using the module.

Comment: Fun fact: That's not a wing, it's a feather. That is because tkinter is based on a Tcl interpreter, and Tcl is pronounced "tickle".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18277350/4777984 this is probably the best solution.

```
import tkinter
import tempfile, base64, zlib

ICON = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode('eJxjYGAEQgEBBiDJwZDBy'
    'sAgxsDAoAHEQCEGBQaIOAg4sDIgACMUj4JRMApGwQgF/ykEAFXxQRc='))

_, ICON_PATH = tempfile.mkstemp()
with open(ICON_PATH, 'wb') as icon_file:
    icon_file.write(ICON)

tk = tkinter.Tk()
tk.iconbitmap(default=ICON_PATH)
label = tkinter.Label(tk, text="Window with transparent icon.")
label.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ok, you are right.

Comment: Thank you all for all the help!

Comment: Acknowledging the answer is on the linked duplicate and then basically copy pasting the code is not how this should be handled. This question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I agree and flagged it duplicate, but the OP was having difficulty finding a solution in the linked duplicate that would work, so I caved, and posted it, sorry for ruining everything.

Comment: It is not ruining everything. However your post could use an explanation as to why this code works. Taking code from another post and not apply any context or reason is not a good practice. there are times where you may need to take an example from another post and modify it to fit the OPs needs but you should provide a link to that post and give credit where credit is due. As well as explain what it is the code is doing.

Comment: I do not know how to link to more than another question, is there a way to link to a specific answer, since the one I posted was not the accepted answer? I could probably cleanup my answer a bit, but I was honestly expecting this to be closed as a duplicate since it is and I had already flagged it, and figured I would help the guy out getting his feather gone, so didn't see much point in spending my entire lunch break developing a well critiqued answer to a duplicate question.

Comment: You can click on the `Share` button and get a link directly to the answer itself. I understand just wanting to help I do that myself. I just try to make it a point to make sure my answer explains the reason for the code. Providing a decent answer helps more than just the OP when other stumble across the post. It is up to you how you wish to answer someone I am just giving you some pointers and if you wish to follow them then great if not then that is up to you as well.

Comment: There we go, I didn't see the "share" button before, learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question
[Set window icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537918/set-window-icon).
Basically you call `root.iconbitmap(path_to_your_icon)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but that didn't worked.

Comment: You will either need to include a blank icon and link to that icon, or embed a blank icon into the code, as indicated in the numerous answers given in the link above.