# How to remove tkinter icon COMPLETELY

Tags: python, tkinter

I know there are lots of questions dealing with the removal of the tkinter icon. And the are lots of answers, but they just describe how to make the icon transparent. If you create a window with a transparent icon and add a title, there is a gap between title and edge of the window.
I already tried:

```
root.iconbitmap(None)
```

but is has no effect. The icon becomes the default icon.
Is there a way to ***REMOVE*** the tkinter icon completely?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not think that there is a way with the  `root.iconbitmap`. An option is to modify the Tkinter module somehow.

Comment: Or just use overrideredirect to hide the title bar?

Comment: `overridedirect()` makes it impossible move or resize the window. I'm Looking for some Attribute something like: `root.attributes('-iconbitmap', False)` (?)

Comment: You can implement the move and resize yourself. It's a trade off for hiding the title bar if you really want to get rid of it

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help.

Comment: You can insert a blank icon

Comment: Did you read my question?

Comment: Use `root.attributes('-toolwindow', True)` but it also removes the 'max/min' buttons as well.

Comment: Thanks, acw1668. That really helped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing the TK icon on a Tkinter window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550050/removing-the-tk-icon-on-a-tkinter-window)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to remove it completely, but you can make it a white icon.
take a look at: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550050/removing-the-tk-icon-on-a-tkinter-window)

```py
import tkinter
import tempfile

ICON = (b'\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x10\x10\x00\x00\x01\x00\x08\x00h\x05\x00\x00'
        b'\x16\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x01\x00'
        b'\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01') + b'\x00'*1282 + b'\xff'*64

_, ICON_PATH = tempfile.mkstemp()
with open(ICON_PATH, 'wb') as icon_file:
    icon_file.write(ICON)

tk = tkinter.Tk()
tk.iconbitmap(default=ICON_PATH)
label = tkinter.Label(tk, text="Window with transparent icon.")
label.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```