# How do I add an image to Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The title pretty much says it all. I'm trying to create a Windows error dialogue for a small project.

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133856/how-to-add-an-image-in-tkinter) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550050/removing-the-tk-icon-on-a-tkinter-window) to create my current code. The intended OS is Windows, but I would prefer cross-platform solutions.

This is my current code:

```
## imports
import base64
import os
import tempfile
import tkinter as tk
import zlib
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

## variables
ICON = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode('eJxjYGAEQgEBBiDJwZDBy'
    'sAgxsDAoAHEQCEGBQaIOAg4sDIgACMUj4JRMApGwQgF/ykEAFXxQRc='))
## main program
# window setup
_, ICON_PATH = tempfile.mkstemp()
with open(ICON_PATH, 'wb') as icon_file:
    icon_file.write(ICON)
root = Tk()
frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frm.grid()
# window content
ttk.Label(frm, text="Windows was not installed properly. Please reinstall Windows.\nError 4 (Windows error 096)").grid(column=1, row=0)
ttk.Button(frm, text="Ok").grid(column=5, row=3)
# window config
root.geometry("+500+500")
root.title("Microsoft Windows")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.iconbitmap(default=ICON_PATH)

widget = ttk.Label(root)
widget.errorImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="""assets\err.png""")
widget["image"] = widget.errorImage
```

When run, it creates the Tk window with text, but no image.
[image: Output:]

Comment: You have forgotten to grid() the widget.errorImage.

Comment: Sry, I mean grid() the Label widget of course.

Comment: You're missing this `widget.grid()` and add `root.mainloop()`

Comment: `widget = ttk.Label(root)` should be `widget = ttk.Label(frm)`

Comment: @toyotaSupra if you add this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to add an image to tkinter?

- You're missing this `widget.grid()` and add `root.mainloop()`
- `widget = ttk.Label(root)` should be `widget = ttk.Label(frm)`